# Receive Email using outlook/Windows Mail from your Synology mail server

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, nas, imap, synology

I got a problem now in the settings in Windows Mail (Outlook) regarding in the POP3 or IMAP.

I am sure I didn't set up any POP3 port and IMAP port in our router. And the only thing that I set up in synology was the SMTP settings coming from our ISP. I can receive and send mail using our mail server.

But as I transfer it to Windows Mail the settings in POP3 or IMAP made me stall. How should I configure this? Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I just typed the mail.ourdomain.com in pop mail server.